# How to discard (reset) process.standardoutput in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

Any ideas on how to discard or reset the contents in a Process.StandardOutput, so we can discard the message of the day and any other initial content of a process?

Comment: I should probably add that its a System.IO.FileStream, so I have no access to seeking or resizing the stream etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to try something similar to:

<strike>Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.SetLength(0);</strike>

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

That way you'll read all content already written and to ignore it. Since that stream doesn't supports seek operations, you user will receive a "headerless" stream.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support seeking.

Comment: In case of CMD it hangs (because CMD always waits for input). Is there any workaraound for CMD?

Answer (score 1):

Does Process.StandardOutput.DiscardBufferedData() not do what you want?

Alternatively just read from it until it's empty?
Not very efficient I guess, but if it's just title fluff then it'll be one read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by discard but you may [redirect the standard output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx):

> When a Process writes text to its
>   standard stream, that text is
>   typically displayed on the console. By
>   redirecting the StandardOutput stream,
>   you can manipulate or suppress the
>   output of a process.

Comment: I'm already redirecting it to a reader. What I need to do is actually discard the contents of the underlying stream before the reader uses it